# VLC 2.2.0 crashes

Tags: vlc

I have problem with VLC 2.2.0 on my Ubuntu 14.10, every time I play video it crash itself. This is error:

```
VLC media player 2.2.0-pre2 Weatherwax (revision 2.2.0-pre1-15-g5178b24)
[0000000001018118] core libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
[00007f116cf1bc88] vdpau_avcodec generic error: unsupported codec 13 or profile -1
Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_r600.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[00007f1180009098] mpgatofixed32 audio converter error: libmad error: bad main_data_begin pointer
[00007f1180009098] mpgatofixed32 audio converter error: libmad error: bad main_data_begin pointer
[00007f1180009098] mpgatofixed32 audio converter error: libmad error: bad main_data_begin pointer
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: HI, this doesn't sound like a question, but as a bug report. You should report bugs by typing in your terminal `ubuntu-bug vlc`

Comment: May be try to add ppa with sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/stable-daily then update apt and reinstall vlc with install --reinstall command.

Answer (score -2):

Uninstall Vlc and install it again using ubuntu software center. The updated version will be downloaded on your system

Comment: This way the version won't change, if the system was upgraded. It look like it was installed from some unstable branch.